# Merge complex entity graph with database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my code first data model I'm retrieving info from ID3 tags and putting it to a database. I have following table relations:

[image: model]

Master entity is Track. Its fields: Artists, Composers, Performers are many to many relationship and Conductor many to one. All of type Artist.

Ids of all entities are generated from hashing various properties on creation of the object:

- In Track it's Path,
- In Album it's Name combined with names of contained Artists and Index field (it's because there may be duplicate album names so to define album uniquely I need to include artists; Index field represents possible multiple discs per album),
- In Picture it's Data,
- The remaining entities Ids are from field Name.

Code for creating Track (with help from [taglib-sharp](https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp)):

```
public Track(string path)
    {
        Path = path;

        using (var f = new AudioFile(path))
        {
            BeatsPerMinute = f.Tag.BeatsPerMinute != 0 ? (int?)f.Tag.BeatsPerMinute : null;
            Index = f.Tag.Track != 0 ? (int?)f.Tag.Track : null;
            Year = f.Tag.Year != 0 ? (int?)f.Tag.Year : null; 

            Comment = f.Tag.Comment;
            Copyright = f.Tag.Copyright;
            Lyrics = f.Tag.Lyrics;
            Title = f.Tag.Title;               



            var artists = f.Tag.Artists.Any() ? f.Tag.Artists : f.Tag.AlbumArtists;
            Artists = new EntityHashSet<Artist>(artists.Select(a => new Artist(a.Trim())));

            Composers = new EntityHashSet<Artist>(f.Tag.Composers.Select(c => new Artist(c.Trim())));

            Performers = new EntityHashSet<Artist>(f.Tag.Performers.Select(p => new Artist(p.Trim())));

            var duplicateComposers = Composers.Where(c => Artists.Any(a => a.Id == c.Id)).ToList();
            (Composers as EntityHashSet<Artist>).ExceptWith(duplicateComposers);
            (Composers as EntityHashSet<Artist>).UnionWith(Artists.Where(a => duplicateComposers.Any(c => c.Id == a.Id)));

            var artistsComposers = Artists.Union(Composers).ToList();
            var duplicatePerformers = Performers.Where(p => artistsComposers.Any(a => a.Id == p.Id)).ToList();
            (Performers as EntityHashSet<Artist>).ExceptWith(duplicatePerformers);
            (Performers as EntityHashSet<Artist>).UnionWith(artistsComposers.Where(a => duplicatePerformers.Any(c => c.Id == a.Id)));

            var artistsComposersPerformers = artistsComposers.Union(Performers).ToList();
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(f.Tag.Conductor))
            {
                Conductor = new Artist(f.Tag.Conductor.Trim());
                var a = artistsComposersPerformers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == Conductor.Id);
                if (a != null)
                {
                    Conductor = a;
                }
            }

            Pictures = new EntityHashSet<Picture>(f.Tag.Pictures.Select(p => new Picture(p)));

            Genres = new EntityHashSet<Genre>(f.Tag.Genres.Select(g => new Genre(g.Trim())));

            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(f.Tag.Album))
            {
                Album = new Album(f.Tag.Album.Trim(), Artists)
                {
                    TrackCount = f.Tag.TrackCount != 0 ? (int?)f.Tag.TrackCount : null,
                    AlbumCount = f.Tag.DiscCount != 0 ? (int?)f.Tag.DiscCount : null,
                    Index = f.Tag.Disc != 0 ? (int?)f.Tag.Disc : null,

                    FrontCover = Pictures.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Type == PictureType.FrontCover),
                    BackCover = Pictures.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Type == PictureType.BackCover) 
                };
            }


        }
    }
```

Code for creating Album:

```
public Album(string name)
        : this()
    {
        Name = name;
    }

public Album(string name, IEnumerable<Artist> artists)
        : this(name)
    {
        var sortedArtists = artists.ToList();
        sortedArtists.Sort();
        Artists = new EntityHashSet<Artist>(sortedArtists);

        Id = Id.WithHash(Index.Value);

        foreach (var artist in sortedArtists)
        {
            Id = Id.WithHash(artist.Id); // WithHash is extension method to combine two hashcodes
        }
    }
```

Ids are set like so:

```
[Required]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            Id = name.ToLowerInvariant().GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

When I insert single Track with the whole graph to the database all is good. I have to check only for possible duplicates in Artists, Composers, Performers and Conductor. Then I can replace references to duplicates to previously added objects with the same Ids.

When I have to insert multiple tracks however, problems start to arise. I don't know how to even approach possible collisions.

For example. I'm adding two tracks with Album name "A". Track 1 have genres "rock; blues", track 2 "blues; metal". Album "A" must be with genres "rock; blues; metal". Also, if this album will have different TrackCount the last one added will determine this value.

To achieve desired results do I have to query the database like crazy in creation of single Track object or is there more elegant solution? Any tips that will get me on the right path are appreciated.